# Activerecord enum doesn't generate helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, enums

I have created an active record enum field: role. Added it to the model and the table. But it doesn't generate the helpers?

**Membership model**

```
  enum role: [:employee, :admin, :owner]

  after_initialize :set_default_membership_role, :if => :new_record?

  def set_default_membership_role
    self.role ||= :employee
  end
```

**pry output**

```
=> [#<Membership id: 1, company_id: 1, user_id: 1, created_at: "2014-11-25 16:06:03", updated_at: "2014-11-25 16:06:03", role: 0>]
[3] pry(main)> @membership.role
from /Users/gtheys/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/gemsets/worke_rs/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:136:in `method_missing'
```

Is it because because Membership is a join model for user and companies?

**model/User.rb**

```
has_many :companies, :through => :memberships, dependent: :destroy
```

**model/Companies.rb**

```
has_many :users, :through => :memberships
```

Or is there another problem why the enum helpers are not created?

Comment: Did you run migration?

Comment: Show me the result `p Membership.column_names` .

Comment: why you need `after_initialize` block? [By default enum value set through database migration.](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/08576b94ad4f19dfc368619d7751e211d23dcad8/activerecord/lib/active_record/enum.rb#L35)

Comment: @ArupRakshit as you can see in the pry output the column role is added to the DB

Comment: Ohh! that is too right. I didn't scroll... :)

Comment: @Зелёный indeed you can do that with DB defaults. I'm just prototyping some application and this was a quick why to switch between defaults without migrating the DB each time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you are calling `.role` on the actual membership model?
In your example (pry output) it looks like `@membership` is an `active_record/relation`.

Try `@membership.first.role`